# объявление строки заранее неизвестной длины

Tags: c, строки

Можно ли в C объявить строку, размерностью которой не является константное значение. Т.е. мы вводим какую-то переменную и по ходу программы объявляем строку, количество элементов которой будет равняться значению этой переменной. Реально ли такое реализовать?

P.S.: добавляю скрин кода, может, поможет найти ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формально - [да](http://www.compiler.su/massivy-peremennoj-dliny-v-c-plus-plus.php). Но это реализовано не везде.

Зато везде можно выделить память динамически, нужное количество с помощью `malloc()`. Потом только нужно не забыть освободить с помощью `free()`.

```
int n;
// Читаем n
char * s = malloc(n); // Создали строку на n символов (с учетом завершающего нулевого)

// Работаем, типа
strcpy(s,...);
strcat(s,...);

// Освобождаем ненужную строку
free(s);
```

Comment: Выдает следующую ошибку для malloc :значение типа "void *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char "

Comment: @Вячеслав161 видимо, "звездочку" забыл после char

Comment: Вы поставили тэг "С"? Ну так и компилируйте как С, а не как С++! В С++ требуется приведение типа - `(char*)malloc`, в С - не нужно. Переименуйте свой файл с расширением `.с` - это разные языки.

Comment: @Harry у него же void* не может преобразоваться в char, а не в char*.

Comment: @Croessmah Думаю, он просто описался. А ошибка с компиляцией не в том режиме - очень распространенная.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, в языке С невозможно "объявить строку" - такого типа данных в языке нет. В языке С строки - это сущности уровня библиотеки, а не уровня языка. Реализуются они на базе массивов с элементами символьного типа.

Во-вторых, начиная со стандарта С99, язык С позволяет вам сделать именно то, что вы описали: объявить массив, размер которого задается переменной, т.е. значением времени выполнения.

```
unsigned n;
/* Вводите значение `n` так, как вам нравится */
scanf("%u", &n);

char str[n];
/* Объявляем массив размера `n` */
```

Имейте в виду, что размер такого массива определяется в момент объявления и остается фиксированным уже навсегда. Последующие изменения в значении переменной `n` никак не будут влиять на размер массива и никаких других средств для изменения размера такого массива в языке нет.

---

Если по каким-то причинам ваш компилятор не поддерживает С99, то объявить массив с таким заранее не известным размером вы не сможете. Придется пользоваться библиотечными средствами динамического выделения памяти, типа `malloc`.

Comment: В моем случае есть только такой вариант: fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &chislo); char str[chislo]; но тут выдается ошибка...

Comment: @Вячеслав161: Разумеется. Каким образом вы будете вводить ваше `chislo` никакой роли не играет. Однако не ясно, что делает `\n` в вашей строке формата `fscanf`.

Comment: @Вячеслав161: Что такое "выдается ошибка" я не знаю. Телепатов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, хотелось бы заметить, что прилагать картинки с экрана - очень плохая идея. Насколько я помню, даже в правилах форума про это говорится. Дело в том, что с этой самой картинки невозможно сделать "копипаст" кода, который Вы показываете и как-то его подправить

Во-вторых, кусочек вашей программы вполне успешно компилируется c помощью gcc версии 5.4. Для clang 3.8 тоже всё нормально.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    unsigned n;

    /* Вводите значение 'n' так, как вам нравится */
    scanf("%u", &n);
    char str[n];

    str[5] = 7;
    printf("Значение : %d\n", str[5]);
}
```

А в третьих, остаётя предположить, что Вы работаете либо с микрософтным компилятором, либо с чем-то для "голого железа". В любом случае:

1. Попробуйте найти в директивах "pragma" задания стандарта языка С и указать соответствующую версию.
2. Когда задаёте подобные вопросы (специфические для компилятора), надо указывать версию компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

Встречал однажды такое или подобное решение:

```
void function(size)
{
    type array[20];
    type *pointer;
    if (size <= sizeof array / sizeof *array)
        pointer = array;
    else
        pointer = malloc(size * sizeof(type));

    // ...
    // какое-то использование pointer
    // ...

    if (pointer != array)
        free(pointer);
}
```

Если массив короткий, то используется массив в стеке. Если длинный, то он резервируется через `malloc`, при этом место в стеке все еще теряется, по крайней мере, при выключенной оптимизации.